# If $p,q$ are prime, solve $p^3-q^5=(p+q)^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $p,q$ are prime, solve $$p^3-q^5=(p+q)^2$$

I can't think of a nice idea for the solution. Since there's a solution $(7;3)$, consisting of two distinct numbers, I really doubt modular arithmetic would help here in any way. I wonder if there's an interesting and simple approach. Thanks.

Comment: $7^3-3^5 = 343-243 = 100 = 10^2 = (7+3)^2$ works. While I cannot prove that this is the only solution, I highly doubt that there are any others because with larger primes the difference between each of the squares become larger as well.

That being said, this reminds me of the equation $p^5-q^3 = p+q$, to which there is (I think) only one solution ($p = 2$, $q = 3$). I think solutions to equations like these are very rare, but like I said, I'm not too sure about how to prove it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's check all the possibilities of $p,q\mod 3$.

1. If $p\equiv1\mod3$ and $q\equiv1\mod3$ then $p^3-q^5\equiv0\mod3$
   and $(p+q)^2\equiv1\mod3$. No solution exists.
2. If $p\equiv-1\mod3$ and $q\equiv-1\mod3$ then $p^3-q^5\equiv0\mod3$
   and $(p+q)^2\equiv1\mod3$. No solution exists.
3. If $p\equiv1\mod3$ and $q\equiv-1\mod3$ then $p^3-q^5\equiv2\mod3$
   and $(p+q)^2\equiv0\mod3$. No solution exists.
4. If $p\equiv-1\mod3$ and $q\equiv1\mod3$ then $p^3-q^5\equiv1\mod3$
   and $(p+q)^2\equiv0\mod3$. No solution exists.

If there is a solution we must have either $p=3$ or $q=3$. It is clear that we cannot have $p=3$. So the only possible solutions are with $q=3$, leading to the equation
$$
p^3=3^5+(p+3)^2.
$$
It is easy to see that $p=7$ is the only solution.